# Declaring & initializing variables with new, outside function scope

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, memory-management, global-variables, new-operator

One of my colleagues declared, and initialized, a global variable using `new`:

```
#define MAX_SIZE_TABLES (1024 * 1024)

unsigned char * ImageBuf = new unsigned char[MAX_SIZE_TABLES];
```

The code compiles and builds with no errors using Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Premium.

My questions:
Is this legal by the standard or undefined behavior?

When is memory deleted if no function calls `delete`?

Edit 1:  added "initialized" after "declared for variables".

Comment: That's what is beautiful in the "polymorphism" of the `new` operator: it ain't `malloc()`, it's (black) magic.

Comment: @H2CO3: I'm quite sure that you can do this with `malloc` as well.

Comment: I have not see this usage of `new` in C++ programs before and didn't know if this a Microsoft feature or not.

Comment: @MooingDuck [You can't.](http://ideone.com/LcuIpd)

Comment: @H2CO3, you can in C++. Your test compares C to C++, that's not a valid test. All global initializers in C must be constants, where the meaning of constant is stricter than in C++

Comment: @JonathanWakely You can't in C (when I start talking about `malloc()`, I imply a context-switch to C, since no sane C++ programmer needs to use `malloc()` in C++ code, unless for the sake of C-compatibility).

Comment: @H2CO3: [you can](http://ideone.com/fl3LEA) in C++, and this question is C++.  My point was merely that `new` is not using black magic in this case.  Sorry for the confusing of using C constructs :(

Comment: @MooingDuck That's C++, not C.

Comment: Yes, but you can't even do `const int i = 0; const int j = i;` at global scope in C, so of course you can't call a function.

Comment: @H2CO3, but your first comment here seems to be saying using `new` at global scope is a property of `new` compared with `malloc` but it's not, it's a property of C++ compared with C. So why bring `malloc` into it? What is black magic about `new`? You're attributing a property of C++ to `new` when it's just a general property of C++

Comment: @JonathanWakely Because `malloc()` is a C function, perhaps? And if you can't have `new` in C, you'll use `malloc()`.

Comment: Keep digging ... `malloc` is also a C++ function, and this is a C++ question, and your first comment seems to imply the OP's question is related to some magical feature of `new` **but it isn't** ... can you not see the distinction? "`new` is not `malloc`, it's magic" is irrelevant and highly misleading and unhelpful. It would have been helpful to say "C++ is not C, it allows dynamic initialization for globals" or something like that

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`new` does not declare variables. It allocates memory. The declaration part is this:

```
unsigned char * ImageBuf
```

The:

```
= new unsigned char[MAX_SIZE_TABLES];
```

part, is the initialization, not the declaration.

It is legal to initialize variables in-place at global scope, including using `new` or a function call. The memory is not freed automatically by the program (manually allocated memory is *never* freed automatically; it doesn't matter where the allocation happens.) When the process exits, memory is freed by the operating system (along with all the usual clean-up, like closing files, etc.) But of course this is platform-specific. From the point of view of the program, memory is never freed during its lifetime.

Comment: I haven't seen `new` used in a global initialization.  This is the specifics of the question:  is using `new` in a global variable initialization legal?

Comment: @ThomasMatthews: You can use virtually any function to initialize global variables, including `new`.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews Yeah, it's legal. I now clarified that in the answer.

Comment: @MooingDuck: Wow, now we can shoot off major limbs, not just shooting ourselves in the foot! Ah, the potential to initialize a global variable using a free standing function that uses other functions and external dependencies!

Comment: @ThomasMatthews: You can even initialize a global from an uninitialized global.  That's a PITA to debug.

Answer (score 4):

It is legal but definitely not recommended. It is a global variable. The memory will be released when the process terminates.

Answer (score 1):

It's OK to do this, but what is the benefit over:

```
 unsigned char ImageBuf[MAX_SIZE_TABLES];
```

This solution takes up a little bit less memory (the size of a pointer + the overhead from `new` allocating memory, at least 16 bytes, quite possibly 40-60 bytes), and the program's code is shorter, but surely neither of those two are drawbacks.

Alternatively, you can do this:

```
unsigned char *ImageBuf;

int main()
{
    ImageBuf = new unsigned char [MAX_SIZE_TABLES];

    ...  all other code that belongs in main ... 

   delete ImageBuf;
}
```

and not have a memory leak.

Comment: So why is defining `ImageBuf` as a global variable (the first alternative here) not a memory leak, while using `new` and not deleting is? Seems like a double standard... `<g>`

Comment: The benefit is that compilers usually have a smaller space for automatic (global) variables than in the dynamic area (heap). The initialization showd that the classical alternative you've presented can be avoided.

Comment: That's news to me. What compilers/OS are we talking about here? I wrote an application in OS/2 in 1990-something that used statically allocated buffers to do serial comms tracing, and it used at a couple of megabytes on either side, to ensure that any lag in the logging would still allow the receiver/sender to continue.

Comment: On my machine, I just compiled a program with g++ to use a 12GB global buffer - yes, I had to use `-mcmodel=large` for it to allow that to build properly. It takes a few seconds to loop through all the 12GB to fill it [my "use" of the variable, to ensure it's actually working].